# Issue in accessing POST parameters in web api controller in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am hitting the controller the controller with the following url :

```
"http://localhost/api/controller/1/2"
```

In the controller I have the following methods:

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostMethod2(string a,string b)

[HttpPost]    
public void PostMethod()
```

The controller is actually hitting the `PostMethod()` but I dont know how to read the parameter values 1 and 2.

Is there any other better way of calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your custom route for this method in Global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapRoute("PostMethod2",
                "api/mycontroller/{a}/{b}",
                new { contorller = "mycontroller", action="PostMethod2"}
            );
```

Or if you're using ASP.NET MVC Web Api you can hook your route in RouteConfig.cs in App_Start folder like so:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "PostMethod2",
                routeTemplate: "api/mycontroller/{a}/{b}",
            );
```

Comment: can I use routes.HttpMaproute instead of routes.maproute?

Comment: Can I use something like this?                  routes.MapHttpRoute("Default API Route",
         "api/{controller}/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}/{id5}",
         new
         {
             id1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
             id2 = UrlParameter.Optional,
             id3 = UrlParameter.Optional,
             id4 = UrlParameter.Optional,
             id5 = UrlParameter.Optional
            
         });